# StreamWriter not creating file?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I wrote a class which outputs a text file. It worked quite well, and it got the job done. However I did the same process, and it didn't work (the file wasn't created). I feel like I'm missing something really simple - what am I missing?

Working code (in the Main Method):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Kinematics hello = new Kinematics();

    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter
        ("C:/Users/myName/Documents/GoogleDrive/folder/folder/Level 3.txt");
    file.WriteLine("Time(s)\tPosition(m)\tVelocity(m/s)\tAcceleration(m/s^2)");
    //create a file to print stuff in.

    file.Close();
    //close the file.
}
```

Not working code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter
           ("C:/Users/myName/Documents/GoogleDrive/folder/folder/hellooo.txt");
        file.WriteLine("Time(s)\tPosition(m)\tVelocity(m/s)\tAcceleration(m/s^2)");

        Projectile ballProjectile = new Projectile();
        ballProjectile.Level1(file);
        ballProjectile.Level2(file);
        ballProjectile.Level3(file); 
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

The file paths are exactly the same and are both correct, and I've double checked that I looked in the right place for the file.

Kinematics does some calculations, and I use the `file.WriteLine();` to write out the outputs of the methods. All the writing is done in the main method. The Level1, Level2, Level3 methods are empty methods as of now. Later they will be running `file.WriteLine();` methods.

Comment: StreamWriter is disposable. Wrap it in a using statement.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c50f5f11-ceda-475d-a1cb-211b8b0fe08f/streamwriter-not-writing-to-file?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Did it throw an exception?

Comment: Nope, there were no exceptions..

Comment: What does `Kinematics` do?

Comment: Put a break point on `file.Close()` - does it ever hit it?

Comment: Yup, I did use break points, went through all that

Comment: So, if you remove the `ballProjectile` code, it all works fine?

Comment: Hmm, so it works by removing the `ballProjectile` and adding `Kinematics hello = new Kinematics();`?

Comment: They're two completely different projects. One piece of code is from one class in one solution and another piece of code is from another class in a different solution altogether.

Comment: When you remove the `ballProjectile` part from the second piece of code it must work, cause its the same as the first one. Build a try catch around your code or go step by step through your code to see where it hangs and whats exactly the error.

Comment: I've gone through every line and all the `ballProjectile` has been commented out. The codes are pretty much exactly the same, with the exception of `kinematics hello`. It doesn't work at all, still.

Comment: And you are sure, that there is no error? Gets the file created? Try writing to `c:\` and use for example only file.writeline ("hi"). After that do a file.close() for testing purpose only.

Comment: I'm using a shared computer, so I can't write straight to c: But I did this:  `System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter
               ("C:/Users/myName/Documents/HELLOOO.txt");
            file.WriteLine(":)");
            file.Close();` - the file isn't even created

Comment: If on a shared computer, are you logged in with your account? I don't think that you would be able to write to another users folder.

Comment: I got it. Visual studio was being a bit picky and stubborn on running one  solution and not the other. Thanks for all the help, and I feel a bit bad it was such a simple thing. Sorry and Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move the `file.Close()` to above the

```
Projectile ballProjectile = new Projectile();
ballProjectile.Level1(file);
ballProjectile.Level2(file);
ballProjectile.Level3(file);
```

Also, as suggested in comments, StreamWriter is disposable and so you should be doing this:

```
var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:/Users/myName/Documents/GoogleDrive/folder/folder/hellooo.txt")

using (file)
{
   file.WriteLine("Time(s)\tPosition(m)\tVelocity(m/s)\tAcceleration(m/s^2)");
}
```

Note the `@` at the start of the file path.

Comment: I did; the file doesn't even show up in the folder where it is supposed to show. Commented out all the projectile stuff for now

Comment: Really strange... did you check your bin directory?

Comment: Where is the bin directory? Using windows

Comment: @AnonE.Muss where your source code is - there should be Debug/Bin somewhere

Comment: Nope, not in bin directory. How could it have worked the first time, but not the second time? I copy/pasted the code from one class to another class, so it's identical. Also, the @ doesn't work; I've tried that

Comment: No idea buddy. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: Do I really need to put something inside the {} in the code that you suggested above? there I have the velocity etc. but do I need to put anything there

Answer (score -1):

I recently had the same problem and I found out that if I run the application as an administrator, it only then creates the file at the desired location. To my surprise, I did not get any exception while creating a StreamWriter object which should create a file if it does not exist.

When I used SaveFileDialog, and tried to save the file to the same location, it then showed me that I do not have permission to write into that directory and I need to select a different path.

I hope this helps someone and saves some time.